# How to get the previous iteration's field value?

Tags: mapping, biztalk

I'm trying to get the value of the a field from the previous node. I need it so that my map can output a normalized data set (i.e. the left side is denormalized).

```
<arrayOrdersItems>
    <OrderItem>
        <Order id1>
        <Item 1>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Order id1>
        <Item 2>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Order id2>
        <Item 1>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Order id3>
        <Item 1>
    </OrderItem>
</arrayOrderItems>
```

Should result in the following:

```
<array>
    <Order>
        <Order id1>
        <Items>
            <Item 1>
            <Item 2>
        </Items>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Order id2>
        <Items>
            <Item 1>
        </Items>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Order id3>
        <Items>
            <Item 1>
        </Items>
    </Order>
</array>
```

The problems I'm facing is that if I try to use xslt, it seems I can specify which index I want for a particular column, but I'm not able to know what column I'm in. Or I have my current index but I can't seem to use it to get at the value of the previous iteration. Or I could do the mapping in two parts (first header/order and then the details/items) but, even then, how do I keep each  tag from being created for each possible  tag?

How is this problem usually handled in Biztalk - I figure I'm just not strong enough in xslt, it seems like it can do nearly anything and I just don't know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use munecian grouping in xslt for achieving this. Below link gives the exact solution you are looking for.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisromp/archive/2008/07/31/muenchian-grouping-and-sorting-in-biztalk-maps.aspx